# How to include .otf in css?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Im trying to include font in css but without success. In console im getting error
in console. But when i include another font with .ttf extension its working. Any suggestion?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Novecentowide-DemiBold';
    src: url("/wp-content/themes/test/fonts/Novecentosanswide-DemiBold.otf"); 
    src: url("/wp-content/themes/test/fonts/Novecentosanswide-DemiBold.otf") format("opentype");
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245141/using-otf-fonts-on-web-browsers

Comment: u see that i already tried that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using an open font you can try using a converter like this one: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
Binding several file formats to the font-face is recommended since not every browser supports every single format by default:
(According to Font Sqirrel)

- TTF Works in most browsers except IE and iPhone.
- EOT IE only.
- WOFF Compressed, emerging standard.
- SVG iPhone/iPad.

Comment: [According to caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=truetype), TTF has been supported on Safari and Chrome for iOS since March of 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you including the font path twice?

Try including it once:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Novecentosanswide-DemiBold'; 
    src: url("/wp-content/themes/test/fonts/Novecentosanswide-DemiBold.otf") format("opentype");
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Also, the font-family and path are different. Font family is Novecentowide-DemiBold and font path is Novecentosanswide-DemiBold. These should be the same. I fixed it for you in the above CSS, assuming the Novecentosanswide-DemiBold is the correct path and not the other one.

You may also need to add a MIME type to your page:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: i tried this but i get an error in console ....and when i try to open that file i get this in browser:"he page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map."

Comment: See my updated answer with a MIME type for your OTF fonts.