# How to host material icons offline?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, materialize

My apologies if this is a very simple question, but how do you use google material icons without a

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

?

I would like my app to be able to display the icons even when the user does not have an internet connection

Comment: This article explains for Angular, thought might be helpful for someone, https://thecodeframework.com/host-google-material-icon-fonts-locally-in-angular-in-5-simple-steps/

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**Method 2. Self hosting** [Developer Guide](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)

> Release 4 changed things a bit, please investigate recommended
> formats and hosting solution.

[Download](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases) release 3.0.2 from github (assets: zip file), unzip, and copy the font folder, containing the material design icons files, into your local project -- https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases

You only need to use the [font](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/font) folder from the archive: it contains the icons fonts in the different formats (for multiple browser support) and boilerplate css.

- Replace the source in the url attribute of `@font-face`, with the relative path to the iconfont folder in your local project, (where the font files are located) eg. `url("iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf")`

> ```
> @font-face {
>    font-family: 'Material Icons';
>    font-style: normal;
>    font-weight: 400;
>    src: url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
>    src: local('Material Icons'),
>         local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
>         url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
>         url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
>         url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
> }
>
> .material-icons {
>   font-family: 'Material Icons';
>   font-weight: normal;
>   font-style: normal;
>   font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
>   display: inline-block;
>   line-height: 1;
>   text-transform: none;
>   letter-spacing: normal;
>   word-wrap: normal;
>   white-space: nowrap;
>   direction: ltr;
>
>   /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
>   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
>   /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
>   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
>
>   /* Support for Firefox. */
>   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
>
>   /* Support for IE. */
>   font-feature-settings: 'liga';
> }
> ```

---

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

---

**NPM / Bower Packages**

Google officially has a Bower and NPM dependency option -- follow Material Icons Guide [1](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)

**Using bower** : `bower install material-design-icons --save`

**Using NPM** : `npm install material-design-icons --save`

**Material Icons** : Alternatively look into Material design icon font and CSS framework for self hosting the icons, from @marella's https://marella.me/material-icons/

---

**Note**

> It seems google has the project on low maintenance mode. The last
> release was, at time of writing, 3 years ago!
>
> There are several issues on GitHub regarding this, but I'd like to
> refer to @cyberalien comment on the issue [`Is this project actively maintained? #951`](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/951#issuecomment-539881377) where it refers several community projects that
> forked and continue maintaining material icons.

---

Comment: How would you do this for a phone GAP app where you would not have a domain?

Comment: target your local folder in the source url of @font-face : url( "iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2" -- updated answer

Comment: Hey, Can you please make an updated answer of this. I have downloaded my mdl icons with npm.

Comment: Solved my problem … I just wanted to note out that we only need the `iconfont` folder from the whole archive.

Comment: for this type of "move cdn resource to be served locally" it usually would pay off to have a solid over 3000 requests average response time data BEFORE and AFTER the change - you would be surprised how-often it is not worth it, regardless of your effort to achieve it ...

Comment: `material-design-icons` is not really usable anymore, it is missing a lot of icons and the installing process sometimes freezes.

Comment: In 2020 there was an update to a new version (4.x). I downloaded the older source code on https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases/tag/3.0.2 which matches the css given above.

Comment: One issue: the stylesheet references four different font formats (.eot, woff, woff2 and ttf) but the Github repo only has ttf. Opening the CSS from Google Fonts in a browser directly will give you a link to the woff2, but that’s all a bit hackish and still no source for eot and woff. (I did check Google’s official documentation, and it is not helpful either.) Any ideas?

Comment: Release tagged 3.0.2 still holds the different formats https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/3.0.2/iconfont

Answer (score 66):

I'm building for Angular 4/5 and often working offline and so the following worked for me.  First install the NPM:

```
npm install material-design-icons --save
```

Then add the following to styles.css:

```
@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

Comment: when call "npm install" wait wait wait lol... but works after long time

Comment: @SergioCabral Luckily you made the comment about waiting, cause there were about 5 times I thought this install isn't going anywhere...  :)

Comment: Thank You Loved It This Is Best Solution Thank You <3

Comment: Working for me also... :)

Comment: any idea how to add outlined icons?

Comment: I followed the npm directions above and all works great, except I am missing two icons: toggle_off and toggle_on. I suspect the npm repo might not be up to date?

Comment: It turns out the google repository is not well maintained. The solution I found is to use npm install material-design-icons-iconfont, a fork of the google repository with many fixes and performance improvements.

Comment: When I use npm install it takes a long time, and then adds no new files to my AspNetCore project. Did anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: @wutzebaer You can use the material-icons package. FMI https://github.com/marella/material-icons#readme

Comment: the `npm install @material-design-icons/font@latest` package is way lighter. import with `@import '@material-design-icons/font';` [docs](https://github.com/marella/material-design-icons/tree/main/font#usage)

Answer (score 34):

The upper approaches does not work for me. 
I download the files from github, but the browser did not load the fonts.

What I did was to open the material icon source link:

**https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons**

and I saw this markup:

```
    /* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v22/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I open the woff font url link **https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v22/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2**

and download the woff2 file.

Then I replace the woff2 file path with the new one in material-icons.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       /* Old file: url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'), */
       /* load new file */ 
       url(2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

That makes thing works for me.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Comment: I solve my issue with this approach, but later I found another git repo, from where I get the proper release.

Comment: @ Kaloyan Stamatov would be nice to share that git repo.. since lot of people have issue with outdated official repo :)

Comment: @Grashopper, I do not have it anymore. Sorry

Comment: more up to date in 2019, this solution worked for me as well.

Comment: this is the only way to get the latest icons that I could find...

Comment: in 8/2020 latest v55 link:  https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v55/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2

Comment: i had to install npm package `npm i material-design-icons` then edited: `apps\appName\src\styles.css` and added the content of the file: `\node_modules\material-design-icons\iconfontmaterial-icons.css` but i had to change the fonts path to be of this format: `url('~material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2')` (added the qutes ' and prefix: `~material-design-icons/iconfont/` before each file name )

Comment: @Shaybc check the date on the npm package. It's old! It's best to get the fonts directly from Google fonts as Kaloyan says above. Or you can get them from GitHub.

Answer (score 29):

As of 2020, my approach is to use the [material-icons-font](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons-font) package.
It simplifies the usage of Google's [material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) package and the community based [material-design-icons-iconfont](https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont).

1. Install the package. `npm install material-icons-font --save`
2. Add the path of the package's CSS file to the style property of your project's angular.json file.

   `...
   "styles": [
       "./node_modules/material-icons-font/material-icons-font.css"
   ],
   ...`
3. If using SCSS, copy content below to the top of your styles.scss file.

   `@import '~material-icons-font/sass/variables';
    @import '~material-icons-font/sass/mixins';
    $MaterialIcons_FontPath: "~material-icons-font/fonts";
    @import '~material-icons-font/sass/main';
    @import '~material-icons-font/sass/Regular';`
4. Use the icons in the HTML file of your project.

   ```
   // Using icon tag
   <i class="material-icons">face</i>
   <i class="material-icons md-48">face</i>
   <i class="material-icons md-light md-inactive">face</i>

   // Using Angular Material's <mat-icon> tag
   <mat-icon>face</mat-icon>
   <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
   <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
   ```

Icons from @angular/material tend to break when developing offline. Adding material-icons-font package in conjunction with @angular/material allows you to use the  tag while developing offline.

Comment: Simple and clean implementation - works perfectly thank you! As the most current and efficient solution, this should be be the accepted answer...

Comment: Is there a way that I can use <mat-icon>face</mat-icon> offline ie., without changing to <i class="material-icons">face</i>

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @Mike. This is the best implementation. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: The simpliest way, thank you for sharing :)

Comment: FYI this package hasn't been updated since 2020. Material is currently at 4.0.

Answer (score 18):

If you use webpack project, after

```
npm install material-design-icons --save
```

you just need to

```
import materialIcons from 'material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'
```

Comment: I don't recommend doing this, this repo is far too big, use one desc. below https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons-iconfont I also noticed that browser will cache https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons and it'll work in the offline mode. Checkout https://keemor.github.io/#/

Comment: I am  newbie in npm can you elaborate `import materialIcons from 'material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'` . We adding this line to where? 
 app.js or somewhere else. I am using framework7 with Vue and I tried. It didn't work for me.

Comment: @SuatAtanPhD you add this import like any other style imports. If you use webpack you need something like style-loader, css-loader and you can place this import anywhere in your js code, for example in index.js or app.js etc.

Comment: Such approach is recommended for building an corporate web application which may work in internal network without access to Internet

Answer (score 17):

**This may be an easy Solution**

---

Get this [repository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons-iconfont) that is a fork of the [original repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) Google published.

Install it with bower or npm

```
bower install material-design-icons-iconfont --save

npm install material-design-icons-iconfont --save
```

Import the css File on your HTML Page

```
<style>
  @import url('node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css');
</style>
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css">
```

Test: Add an icon inside body tag of your HTML File

```
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

If you see the face icon, you are OK.

If does not work, try add this `..` as prefix to `node_modules` path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css">
```

Comment: Employing the _material-design-icons-iconfont_ package works even with the Angular's standard `mat-icon` component. Thus the transition is seamless.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, except the stylesheet link in index.html didn't work - I had to add an import into my Styles.scss file: 

    `@import"../node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";`

Then my locally hosted icons leapt into life

Comment: Also, importing into your scss means that it is a build time dependency and you can NPM install --dev to not make it part of the prod node environment footprint.

Answer (score 11):

### To Avoid

`npm i material-design-icons`

[Google isn't publishing any new version to their npm repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/1085), so please **avoid using the `npm i material-design-icons`** since the last publish was 5 years ago.

### To use

1. Download the needed font from [their repo](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/font). *you can ignore the `.codepoints` extension.* Be aware, they do not have `.woff2` and `.woff` type anymore, but `.ttf` or `.otf` [works just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245187/11135174).
2. Add them to your assets folder
3. Into a css file, do add the following

```scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
    url('/assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-size: 24px; /* Preferred icon size */
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  font-style: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

4. Then add the `.material-icons` class

```html
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

*Angular users do not need to add `.material-icons` if they already use `mat-icon`*

### Outline & Regular at the same time

Both, outline & regular one?
Here is the step.

I'm using the scss `@extend` method for that purpose because I'm lazy.

```scss
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local('Material Icons Outlined'), local('MaterialIconsOutlined-Regular'),
    url('/assets/fonts/MaterialIconsOutlined-Regular.otf') format('truetype');
  font-display: fallback;
}

.material-icon {
  // Same content as the previous example without the `font-family`
}

.material-icons {
  @extend .material-icon;
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
}

.material-icons-outlined {
  @extend .material-icon;
  font-family: 'Material Icons Outlined';
}
```

```html
<mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined" svgIcon="dark_mode-outline"></mat-icon>
```

Comment: Just a question for this: If I want to use `regular` as well as `outline` ==> how to define it in the `font-face`? Just a new entry with the same `font-familiy`? And then how to use the `outline` vs. the `regular` in a `<mat-icon>`? Some kind of `font-set`?

Comment: Hi, thx for the very quick and helpful reply. When I follow your link about the repro I find the Material font and a hint for the variablefont. Right now we're using Angular 14 and many of the outlined icons wont work. Therefore I happy to have your solution. Nevertheless the question arise if we should use the variablefont or not. Is there somewhere a useful link about what's the difference, how to use, etc?

Comment: @LeO Glad I could help. I'm not aware of any better solution yet. But feel free to add a comment here if you find anything useful & I'll be glad to update my answer. 

I have to say, my bet is  that google will release something with their new icon set & animation. This is one of the reason why this workaround works for now and why I wouldn't invest to much time into it.

Cheers

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: One needs to set (in `.material-icon`) the `width` and `height` to `24px` and the `margin` to `0`. Otherwise it might happen that the Icon shrinks too much in a `flex` and some parts are truncated as consequence. Perhaps you can update as well your answer :-)

Answer (score 10):

### Use [material-design-icons-iconfont](https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont)

> Full disclosure, I'm the author of this package
>
> Google's [material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) project is **on low maintenance**
>   and **out of date for a while**. There's a gap between the version in
>   https://material.io/icons/ and the version in
>   [material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons).

I've created [material-design-icons-iconfont](https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont) to address these major issues:

- [material-design-icons](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) jams `npm install` - all irrelevant svg/xml/... files has been removed
- Font files are always up-to-date straight from `Google Fonts` CDN
- Support for scss

---

#### Install via `npm`

```
npm install material-design-icons-iconfont --save
```

It depends on how you pack your web application (`webpack`/`gulp`/`bower`/...), you'll need to import the `.css`/`.scss` file (and might change the relative fonts path)

---

**Import Using SCSS**

Import in one of your sass files

```
$material-design-icons-font-path: '~material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/fonts/';
@import '~material-design-icons-iconfont/src/material-design-icons';
```

Later on, reference your desired icon `<i class="material-icons">` + icon-id + `</i>`

```
<i class="material-icons">contact_support</i>
```

- read the full instructions on [material-design-icons-iconfont](https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont) for more import methods

---

#### Demo page

It comes with a light [demo page](https://jossef.github.io/material-design-icons-iconfont/) to assist searching and copy-pasting fonts

[image]

Comment: I'm having a problem with PWA. Icons are working while you are in browser but once you add shortcut on home screen and run the app icons are not showing.

Answer (score 8):

My recipe has three steps:

1. to install material-design-icons package

   ```
   npm install material-design-icons
   ```
2. to import material-icons.css file into .less or .scss file/ project

   ```
   @import "~/node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
   ```
3. to include recommended code into the reactjs .js file/ project

   ```
   <i className='material-icons' style={{fontSize: '36px'}}>close</i>
   ```

Comment: this package not exist any more

Comment: with angular cli, do npm install material-design-icons and then add css in angular.json -> architect->build->styles

Answer (score 7):

I have tried to compile everything that needs to be done for self-hosting icons in my answer.
You need to follow these 4 simple steps.

1. Open the iconfont folder of the materialize repository

   link-
   https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont
2. Download these three icons files ->

   **MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2** - format('woff2')

   **MaterialIcons-Regular.woff** - format('woff')

   **MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf** - format('truetype');

   Note- After Download you can rename it to whatever you like.
3. Now, go to your **CSS** and add this code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

---

**Note : The address provided in src:url(...) should be with respect to the 'CSS File' and not the index.html file. For example it can be  src : url(../myicons/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2)**

---

4. You are ready to use now and here is how it can be done in HTML

```html
<i class="material-icons">face</i>
```

Click [here](https://material.io/icons/) to see all the icons that can be used.

Comment: 404 on your link

Answer (score 4):

2019 Update here:

To self host your material icons, the Regular ones, Rounded, Sharp, all the variants.
Go get them from this repo:
https://github.com/petergng/material-icon-font

For some reason I dont know why these fonts are not easily accessible from Google repositories.

But here you go.

After downloading the package, go to bin folder and you'll see the four variants.
Of course, it is up to you to use whichever.

To use them, create a css file and

1. Generate a font face for each variant you need:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(./icons/regular/Material-Icons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
    src: local('Material-Icons-Regular'),
    url(./icons/regular/Material-Icons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
    url(./icons/regular/Material-Icons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
    url(./icons/regular/Material-Icons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons Round';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(./icons/round/Material-Icons-Round.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
    src: local('Material-Icons-Round'),
    url(./icons/round/Material-Icons-Round.woff2) format('woff2'),
    url(./icons/round/Material-Icons-Round.woff) format('woff'),
    url(./icons/round/Material-Icons-Round.svg) format('svg'),
    url(./icons/round/Material-Icons-Round.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons Sharp';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(./icons/sharp/Material-Icons-Sharp.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
    src: local('Material-Icons-Sharp'),
    url(./icons/sharp/Material-Icons-Sharp.woff2) format('woff2'),
    url(./icons/sharp/Material-Icons-Sharp.woff) format('woff'),
    url(./icons/sharp/Material-Icons-Sharp.svg) format('svg'),
    url(./icons/sharp/Material-Icons-Sharp.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

The `url` will link to where the icons are located in your project.

2. Now lets register the icon classes:

```css
.material-icons-outlined, .material-icons {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    direction: ltr;
}
```

This will make both
`.material-icons-outlined,`
and
`.material-icons` classes use the same defaults.
If you want to to use `.material-icons-sharp`, just append it to the two class names.

3. Finally, let us plug-in the font face you pulled in from step 1.

```css
.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

```css
.material-icons-outlined {
    font-family: 'Material Icons Outline';
}
```

Again, to use more variant, like Sharp, just add its block like the two above.

Once done...go to your html and use your newly minted icons.

```
<i class="material-icons-outlined">hourglass_empty</i>
```

```
<i class="material-icons">phone</i>
```

Answer (score 3):

After you have done `npm install material-design-icons`, add this in your main CSS file:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(~/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url(~material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
       url(~material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
       url(~material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With angular cli

```
npm install angular-material-icons --save
```

or

```
npm install material-design-icons-iconfont --save
```

material-design-icons-iconfont is the latest updated version of the icons. angular-material-icons is not updated for a long time

Wait wait wait install to be done and then add it to angular.json -> projects -> architect -> styles

```
 "styles": [
          "node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

or if you installed material-desing-icons-iconfont then

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

Answer (score 2):

On http://materialize.com/icons.html the style header information you include in the page,you can go to the actual Hyperlink and make localized copies to use icons offline.

Here's how.NB: You will download two Files in all **icon.css** and **somefile.woff**.

1. Go to the following URL as required in the header

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` .

Save page as whatever_filename.css. Default is icon.css

2. Look for a line like this

`src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v22/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2)`

3. Visit the URL that has .woff ending it

`https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v22/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2` . Your browser will automatically download it. Save it in your CSS folder.

4. You should now have the two files **icon.css** and **2fcrYFNa....mY.wof22**, save them both in your css. Now make edits in your css header location to the icon.css in your directories. Just make sure the .woff2 file is always in the same folder as the icon.css. Feel free to edit the long file names.

Answer (score 2):

The question title asks how to **host** material icons offline but the body clarifies that the objective is to **use** the material icons offline *(emphasis mine)*.

Using your own copy of the material icons files is a valid approach/implementation.  Another, for those that can use a [service worker](https://jakearchibald.github.io/isserviceworkerready/) is to let the service worker take care of it.  That way you don't have the hassle of obtaining a copy and keeping it up to date.

For example, generate a service worker using [Workbox](https://workboxjs.org/#get-started), using the simplest approach of running workbox-cli and accepting the defaults, then append the following text to the generated service worker:

```
workboxSW.router.registerRoute('https://fonts.googleapis.com/(.*)',
workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({
  cacheName: 'googleapis',
  cacheExpiration: {
    maxEntries: 20
  },
  cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}
})
);
```

You can then check it was cached in Chrome using F12 > Application > Storage > IndexedDB and look for an entry with googleapis in the name.

Comment: I got this to work also with some small changes. I changed "workboxSW" to "workbox". I changed "router" to "routing" and added this code into my sw_config.js file that gets generated when using the workbox cli wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Kaloyan Stamatov method is the best.
First go to https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons. and copy the css file.
the content look like this

```css
/* fallback */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v37/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');
}
    
.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Paste the source of the font to the browser to download the woff2 file
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v37/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2
Then replace the file in the original source. You can rename it if you want
No need to download 60MB file from github. Dead simple
My code looks like this

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(materialIcon.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

while materialIcon.woff2 is the downloaded and replaced woff2 file.

Comment: Doesn't work on all browsers, see this SO answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002820/why-should-we-include-ttf-eot-woff-svg-in-a-font-face

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using this package (@mdi/font) and importing it on main.js:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

While I was also facing this same challenge on my angular material project, I came up with a working offline solution. save all the details.

After downloading the resource, just follow these steps on the README.md file

## STEP 1

Copy the distribution into your project

## STEP 2

import the stylesheets in your angular.json imports array

## Example

```
`angular.json [
        {
            style[
                "css/material.css", "css/icons.css"
            ]
        } `
```

## STEP 3

You should see your icons appear offline after your next auto reload.

`Optionally`, you can comment or take out this line  `https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons` from your `index.html` file.

`HAPPYCODING :)`

I created an offline repository for [ngMatIcons](https://github.com/potterinc/ngMatIcon) you can download it from this link. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this in case it helps someone... This might not work for your use case, but it might work for someone. I have an offline computer where I use an app that uses materialize. I was also trying to solve this problem, but that github repo is huge, and I was having a difficult time following all the instructions. Additionally, the `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` tag was slowing the opening of my app on the offline computer, as it kept trying to download that file, but couldn't.

Here is what I did (working example at the bottom of this comment)

1. Download the file at https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons and store it as a local css file in your website directory. **This file will require one modification, explained in step 3.**
2. Add a `<link>` tag to `index.html` pointing to the file you saved in step 1. (For example, I saved https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons to assets/css/materialize_offline_files/materialize-icons.css in my website directory, then added this to index.html: `<link href="assets/css/materialize_offline_files/materialize-icons.css" rel="stylesheet"> rel="stylesheet">`.) *Note: Make sure to add this link tag before your materialize.css imports.*
3. **Modification to file from step 1.** If you look at the file at https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons, you'll find this line of css code for the fall back font: `src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v139/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');`. **Download the file at that src url, https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v139/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2**, save it to the same directory as materialize_icons.css (the file from step 1), and change that line of code to: `src: url("flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2") format('woff2');`

Working example (4 files):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="assets/css/materialize_offline_files/materialize-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Hello!
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

**assets/css/materialize_offline_files/materialize-icons.css**

```
/*
 * File downloaded from https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons
 * with slight modification (src url of fallback font)
 */

/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  /**src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v139/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2');*/
  src: url("flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2") format('woff2');
  /**
   * flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2 is the file
   * downloaded from 
   * https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v139/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2
   * NOTE:: css src url attributes are relative to the css file,
   * so store flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2
   * IN THE SAME DIR as this css file, for that modification to work.
   */
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Finally (remaining 2 files), make sure you have the files:

- **assets/css/materialize.min.css** (download it from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css)
- **assets/css/materialize_offline_files/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2** (download it from https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v139/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2

I thought this would just eliminate the problem the call to fonts.googleapis.com slowing down my app, but actually the few icons I use are actually showing up on the offline computer now. I'm not sure if it will work for all the icons, but it is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are all old. In 2023 you want [material-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-icons) npm package NOT `material-design-icons`. It's much better maintained and automatically updated.

`npm install material-icons --save`

It's one line of code to get it working:

```
import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

OR

```
@import 'material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

There are other alternatives to get it working but see the linked docs for more.

Answer (score 0):

Install npm package

```
npm install material-design-icons --save
```

Put css file path to styles.css file

```
@import "../node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way there is video available on YouTube with step by step instructions.

https://youtu.be/7j6eOkhISzk

1. These are the steps. Download materialize icon package from https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/releases
2. Copy the icon-font folder and rename it to icons.
3. Open the materialize.css file and update the following paths:

a. from url(MaterialIcons-Regular.eot) to url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot)
b. from url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2') to  url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2')
c. from url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff') to url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff')
d. from url(MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype') to url(../fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype')

3. Copy the materialize-icon.css to your css folder and reference it in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

I chose a lazy solution with apache to evade dissuasions:

```
<link href="https://MYHOST/gfonts/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://MYHOST/gfonts/icon?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined" rel="stylesheet">
```

Add small apache plugin

```
a2enmod substitute
```

And in my apache config

```
AddOutputFilterByType INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
Substitute "s|https://fonts.gstatic.com/|/gsfonts/|i"
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass "/gfonts/"  "https://fonts.googleapis.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/gfonts/"  "https://fonts.googleapis.com/"
ProxyPass "/gsfonts/"  "https://fonts.gstatic.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "/gsfonts/"  "https://fonts.gstatic.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can automate downloading the latest font and subsetting it from a Node.js script.

**1. Downloading**

Google API ignores requests which don't have a proper user-agent header. We can use **user-agents** to bypass the restriction. Please, don't abuse it :)

Go to [Material icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.query=rocket), choose one and copy the link HTML that contains the path to the CSS file. It looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
```

You can actually edit the parameters here to get the exact font that you want.
This API should be stable enough.

Now, we need to download this CSS file and parse the URL of the actual binary font file. This function can do it for you, just give it the **link** string and the path where to save the file:

```
const downloadFont = async (googleFontLink, fullFontPath) => {
  const headers = {
    Accept: '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'font/woff2',
    'User-Agent': new UserAgent().toString(),
  };
  const cssUrl = googleFontLink.match(/href="(.*?)"/)[1];
  const fontCssRes = await axios.get(cssUrl, { headers });
  const fontUrl = (fontCssRes.data.match(/url\((.*?)\)/) || [])[1];

  const fontFileRes = await axios.get(fontUrl, {
    headers,
    responseType: 'stream',
  });
  await fontFileRes.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fullFontPath));

  const delay = time => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, time));
  await delay(1000);
};
```

**2. Mapping the ligatures**

**Fontkit** will help here. It can decode the woff2 file. You just need a little script to extract the ligatures. Something like this:

```
const getLigatures = () => {
  const result = {};
  const font = fontkit.openSync(fullFontPath);

  const lookupList = font.GSUB.lookupList.toArray();
  const lookupListIndexes = font.GSUB.featureList[0].feature.lookupListIndexes;

  lookupListIndexes.forEach(index => {
    const subtables = lookupList[index].subTables;

    subtables.forEach(subTable => {
      const leadingCharacters = [];
      subTable.extension.coverage.rangeRecords.forEach(coverage => {
        for (let i = coverage.start; i <= coverage.end; i++) {
          let character = font.stringsForGlyph(i)[0];
          leadingCharacters.push(character);
        }
      });
      const ligatureSets = subTable.extension.ligatureSets.toArray();

      ligatureSets.forEach((ligatureSet, ligatureSetIndex) => {
        const leadingCharacter = leadingCharacters[ligatureSetIndex];

        ligatureSet.forEach(ligature => {
          const character = font.stringsForGlyph(ligature.glyph)[0];
          if (!character) return;

          const ligatureText =
            leadingCharacter +
            ligature.components.map(x => font.stringsForGlyph(x)[0]).join('');
          const code = character
            .charCodeAt(0)
            .toString(16)
            .toLowerCase();
          const iconName = ligatureText.toLowerCase();

          result[iconName] = code;
        });
      });
    });
  });

  return result;
};
```

You can filter this dictionary to get the codes of those icons that you actually want. You just need to pass these codes to the script that will create a subset.

**3. Subsetting**

In my project there's 155 icons. The entire font is 3268. Why would I host the whole thing?

I was not able to find a javascript library that can properly subset and save the result in woff2. But there's a Python script **fonttools** that does it just fine.

You need to install Python, make sure it works in the terminal and install fonttools with a couple of dependencies:

```
pip install fonttools zopfli brotli
```

Then you build the console command like this:

```
const getCommand = unicodes => {
  return `fonttools subset ${fullFontPath} \
  --unicodes=5f-7a,30-39,${unicodes.join(',')} \
  --no-layout-closure \
  --output-file=${resultFontPath} \
  --flavor=woff2`;
};
```

...and run it with **child_process.exec**.

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install material-design-icons
```

and

```
@import '~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css';
```

worked also for me with Angular Material 8

Answer (score -1):

Added this to the web config and the error went away

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" /> 
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" /> 
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
```