# How to host Material Design icons offline?

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, materialize, google-fonts

I want to host Material Icons offline for my offline web development project (I will not have internet on the computer where is deployed). From my Google search, I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270835/how-to-host-material-icons-offline#answer-37271195). BUT it is Not working for me. My question is how to make it work. How to host material design icons offline for my offline project?

I have attached [a .zip file of my SSCCE project, which reproduces the problem, here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/0dsd97tf3g8al85/MaterialFontsOffline.zip).

Basically I downloaded the `MaterialIcons-Regular.eot`, `MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf`, `MaterialIcons-Regular.woff` and `MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2` from here and put them in my project's directory.

Here is my index file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>MaterializeTest</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="material-fonts.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="materialize.min.css" />

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1"/>

    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the CSS file.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Material Icons';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   src: url(MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
   src: local('Material Icons'),
        local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
        url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
        url(MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

Comment: Have you read this [instruction](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/)?

Comment: @VladislavKievski Yes, I have followed the 'Setup Method 2. Self hosting' section. You can download my example little project from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/0dsd97tf3g8al85/MaterialFontsOffline.zip). I have also copied the code snippets above.

Comment: try to prepend file like this: `url("./MaterialIcons-Regular.eot")` and all other locations.. and see if it loads ok,, also try to add quotes

Comment: @KresimirPendic But `./` is prepended to `exe`s. Isn't it?

Comment: try to add mime type fix,, I added answer lower

Comment: @KresimirPendic OK

Comment: For someone using Angular, this post might be helpful https://thecodeframework.com/host-google-material-icon-fonts-locally-in-angular-in-5-simple-steps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you downloaded wrong files from somewhere. This is the path that you have to download correct fonts from: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont or use the one in my GH repo that worked for you already.

Also you need to call only one css in your html (php) file, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="material-fonts.css" />
```

hth, k

Comment: By global file, do you mean `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file?

Comment: @Sie that depends on platform you are in,, I can see that for ubuntu it's `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` but I'm not sure, I'm on nginx

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache2, and  I added those lines at the end of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and restarted apache. But I still have the same problem. Material Icons are not rendering.

Comment: can you share your url (if it's not private or localhost one) so I can see and try to investigate your case?

Comment: Hey it's localhost, but let me try to deploy it in cloudnine servers. Then I'll give you the URL. Hey but I will do it in one and a half hour, as I am late for class.

Comment: Hi. Firstly, sorry for late. Secondly, [here I uploaded this project on Github](https://github.com/JessieSie/MaterialFontsOffline). Will you be able to take a look or try to fix my problem?

Comment: hi @Sie you can test my repo pull that I sent you,, this is public html file that works you can see it here: https://rawgit.com/mkteam/MaterialFontsOffline/f0e2eac5bf1b5c4d8e5e92f3a73a5c9970593dfb/index.html

Comment: Hi, this works. Thank you so very much indeed. After some testing, I have concluded that it is the actual font files you have replaced mine with, have made the difference. So can you tell me where did you get those font files?

Comment: Secondly can you edit the answer accordingly, so that I can mark this answer as the accepted answer to this question. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**First way to add icons will be following:**

1. Copy content of this file to you custom css file (for instance, material-fonts.css) https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons

```css
/* fallback */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v29/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

2. Copy the link from src url and put it in browser. It will download file. You need to put it file in the same directory where you save first file(material-fonts.css).
3. Update in material-fonts.css file `src: url()` as `src: url(2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');`

**Second example:**
Looks like you download wrong files.
You need to download this [directory](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont) and put it into your folder, previous files have to removed.

Your materialFontTest.php should look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>MaterializeTest</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="material-icons.css" />

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am unable to interpret the 2nd point. Can you recheck it. I think there are typos. It is grammatically and semantically unclear sentence. Thank you

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: Please see my example project (which demonstrates the problem) [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/0dsd97tf3g8al85/MaterialFontsOffline.zip). The material icons are Not rendered.

Comment: I added second solution. Could you please try it?

Comment: Can I try it in half an hour?

Answer (score 4):

**Original but light weight Material Icons**

This light-weight repository (https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-design-icons-iconfont) is a fork of the original repository of ~60MB but this is very much light weight because unnecessary files were removed from that original repository.

### How to install?

#### step 1:

```
// install via bower/npm
bower install material-design-icons-iconfont

npm install material-design-icons-iconfont
```

#### step 2:

```
// import or link
@import "~material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css";

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css">
```

## How to use?

```
<i class='material-icons'>done</i> // remember to add class `material-icons`
```

more on https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline