# @material-ui/core icons not showing when offline

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I started working on a React project that uses @material-ui/core , @material-ui/icons for displaying icons.
the thing is those icons are not showing when offline
an i get this error when i inspect my console:
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons net:: ERR_NETWORK
how can i fix it .
i'll appreciat your help

Comment: Looks like here is the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37271195/3508399

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.