# How do I get Angular 13 to include CSS when running without an Internet connection?

Tags: css, angular, spring-boot, gradle, angular-material

**Update 1/2/22**: I downgraded to version `11.1.2` (same version as another app of mine which didn't have this issue) and the issue no longer appears.  While this allows me to move forward, I more or less circumvented the issue than resolved it.  I'll leave this open and hopefully a true fix can be discovered.

**Original Post**:

I need my Angular `13.0.0`  app to run offline (no Internet) and in a war with embedded tomcat.  The initial page is a login page and the HTML and Javascript (compiled TS) seem to work fine as logging in reaches the back end successfully and the home page loads.  Upon commenting out my `styles.scss` file and running online, I'm seeing the exact issue.  In addition, **running offline via Angular CLI does *not* produce this issue**.

**I can literally leave the executable war running and disable my wifi to go from having CSS to not having it**.  The opposite is also true.  Based on that, the issue appears to be completely in the front end.

I've done this with other applications but older versions (`11.1.2` and `10.0.0-rc.6` and *not* using embedded containers) this issue doesn't occur.  I've reviewed the `angular.json` files from those applications and I don't see any glaring differences.  Did something change in the newer versions of Angular?  Otherwise, there’s something I may be missing due to the container being embedded.

The entire app is missing CSS but to keep it simple here is how my login page looks:

- Offline:
  [image]
- Online:

[image]

Here is my `angular.json`:

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "client": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../src/main/resources/static",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "sourceMap": true,
              "optimization": false
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "20mb",
                  "maximumError": "25mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "20mb",
                  "maximumError": "25mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build:development"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "client:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "client:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "client-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "client:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "client:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "client"
}
```

And my client `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "3.1.1"
}

node {
  version = '17.0.1'
  npmVersion = '8.1.0'
  download = true
  workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/node")
  nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
}

task buildClient(type: NpmTask) {
  group = 'build'
  description = 'Compile client side assets for production'
  args = ['run', 'build:prod']
}
buildClient.dependsOn(npm_install)
```

And finally, my main `build.gradle` file (there are only two):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.4.3'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.group.'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task deleteStaticFolder(type: Delete) {
    def dirName = "src/main/resources/static"
    file( dirName ).list().each{
        f ->
            delete "${dirName}/${f}"
    }
}

processResources.dependsOn('client:buildClient')
println 'Using build.gradle'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.3.9.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '2.5.6'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-csv
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-csv', version: '2.13.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch
    implementation group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.55'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.unboundid/unboundid-ldapsdk
    implementation group: 'com.unboundid', name: 'unboundid-ldapsdk', version: '5.1.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-websocket
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version: '2.5.6'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I've spent way too much time on this and I'm out of ideas.  Things I’ve tried:

- ***Update 12/28/21*** - created a simple CSS class (changing the background color) in `styles.scss` and referenced it in the login component template.  With an Internet connection, the class was applied, without a connection it was not.
- Different things in the `angular.json` related to architect/build/configurations/production`
- Commenting out the RequestFilter class in my spring boot code
- Cleared browser cache to make sure online/offline comparisons are accurate

Network tab:

- Offline:
  [image]
- Online:
  [image]

Console:

- Offline:
  [image]
- Online:
  [image]

The missing theme console warning is suspicious but as it appears even when the CSS is working I am not convinced it's related.

Finally, the Roboto font error is also present in the console for my other apps but doesn't impact their CSS so again I don't believe is causing my CSS to be MIA.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see this answer:
I will hope help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270835/how-to-host-material-icons-offline

Comment: To have your angular resources in handy, you can use the `@angular/pwa` or `@angular/service-worker`

Comment: @Mahyar8520 thanks but my issue is not with the icons, it's with all CSS.

Comment: @Pieterjan this sounds promising.  I'll take a look, thanks.

Comment: @Pieterjan I followed this tutorial on `service-workers`: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-service-worker/ but the issue remains.  When I reach the login page (while offline), the CSS is gone and my browser's `Application/Cache Storage` shows an entry for `ngsw:/:db:control - http://localhost:8444` but there are no cache entries.  It seems like there should be some entries there.  In `ngsw-config.json`, the assetGroup for app has an installMode of `prefetch` which I believe includes it in the build.  Do you have any suggestions?