# Angular Material and changing fonts

Tags: angular, angular-material

Just wondering how I can change default fonts in Angular Material ...

The default is Roboto and I couldn't find a way to change this to different font.

Comment: look at this issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/205

Comment: I think the problem with Material styling is that yes you can change the global font and styles, but sometimes you just want use the defaults and change just parts, and not everyone is using SASS. After all the whole point of material components is their plug and play usability.  So I adopted a view of just making the changes as required using the ::ng-deep syntax on just the components that needed them.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can use the [CSS universal selector (`*`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) in your `CSS` or `SCSS`:

```css
* {
  font-family: Raleway /* Replace with your custom font */, sans-serif !important; 
  /* Add !important to overwrite all elements */
}
```

Starting from Angular Material `v2.0.0-beta.7`, you can customise the typography by creating a typography configuration with the `mat-typography-config` function and including this config in the `angular-material-typography` mixin:

```scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Raleway'
);

@include angular-material-typography($custom-typography);
```

Alternatively (`v2.0.0-beta.10` and up):

```scss
// NOTE: From `2.0.0-beta.10`, you can now pass the typography via the mat-core() mixin:
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Raleway'
);
@include mat-core($custom-typography);
```

Refer to [Angular Material's typography documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) for more info.

---

Note: To apply the fonts, add the `mat-typography` class to the parent where your custom fonts should be applied:

```html
<body class="mat-typography">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Comment: As of V12 it is --- mat.define-typography-config($font-family: 'Raleway') --- and don't forget to import the new font's CDN

Comment: this assumes Im using Sass right? what if i just have normal css

Comment: @rex Newer versions of Angular Material (v15+) now use the theming system from Material Components for Web, which uses CSS variables. (I'm not aware as to whether older versions of Angular Material used CSS variables though)

Answer (score 97):

From this [official guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#customization):

> Typography customization is an extension of Angular Material's
> Sass-based theming. Similar to creating a custom theme, you can create
> a custom typography configuration.

So, include this line in your `index.html` file, linking to some external font:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then put in your `styles.scss` file the custom typography settings, adjusting the font-family string for the selected font:

```scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$custom-typography: mat-typography-config($font-family: '"Oswald", sans-serif;');
@include mat.core($custom-typography);
```

A full custom theme, with colors and all, is something like:

```scss
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

$custom-typography: mat-typography-config($font-family: '"Oswald", sans-serif;');
@include mat.core($custom-typography);

$custom-primary: mat.define-palette($mat-blue);
$custom-accent: mat.define-palette($mat-amber);
$custom-theme: mat.define-light-theme($custom-primary, $custom-accent);
@include mat.all-component-themes($custom-theme);
```

That's it.

You can find more info about custom typography in [this post](https://medium.com/@bogac/customization-of-an-angular-material-2-theme-typography-components-3ca5584f36ca).

The font used in the samples are from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/selection?selection.family=Oswald).

**Update:**

As commented by [@Nate May](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10235442/nate-may), it changed with v12, so check the [updated documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography) about the current recommendation for custom typography.

Comment: How to import a .otf font file instead of using a CDN link?

Comment: About using .oft fonts, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245187/1621107).

Comment: As of V12 it is --- mat.define-typography-config($font-family: '"Oswald", sans-serif;') --- and don't forget to import the new font's CDN

Comment: As pointed by @NateMay, it changed with v12, so check [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography).

Comment: Thanks, worked for me with Angular 11, but using `mat-core` instead of `mat.core`

Comment: This no longer works in V15 as mat.core() no longer takes any arguments.  I've looked at the material documentation but I still can't figure out how to change the font.  Worked in previous versions.  Here is my code:
`use '@angular/material' as mat;`
`use "sass:map";`

`$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Poppins'
);
`
`@include mat.core($custom-typography); // fails here`

Answer (score 16):

**Starting Angular 15, previous most voted answer will no longer work**.

**1. Concerning Typography**

You can define it just like you showed, but keep in mind that when you change the font, **you will probably have to change typography sizes**.

If you want to do it, here is a working example:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$typography-config: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: '"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
  $headline-1: mat.define-typography-level(112px, 112px, 300, $letter-spacing: -0.05em),
  $headline-2: mat.define-typography-level(56px, 56px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.02em),
  $headline-3: mat.define-typography-level(45px, 48px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.005em),
  $headline-4: mat.define-typography-level(34px, 40px, 400),
  $headline-5: mat.define-typography-level(24px, 32px, 400),
  $headline-6: mat.define-typography-level(20px, 32px, 400),
  $subtitle-1: mat.define-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400),
  $body-1: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
  $body-2: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 20px, 400),
  $subtitle-2: mat.define-typography-level(16px, 28px, 400),
  $caption: mat.define-typography-level(12px, 20px, 400),
  $button: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 14px, 500),
);
```

**In your theme definition**, don't forget to add defined typography configuration

```
$light-primary: mat.define-palette($light-primary-palette, 500);
$light-accent: mat.define-palette($light-accent-palette, 500);
$light-warn: mat.define-palette($light-warn-palette, 500);

$theme-light: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $light-primary,
    accent: $light-accent,
    warn: $light-warn
  ),
  typography: $typography-config
));

$dark-primary: mat.define-palette($dark-primary-palette, 500);
$dark-accent: mat.define-palette($dark-accent-palette, 500);
$dark-warn: mat.define-palette($dark-warn-palette, 500);

$theme-dark: mat.define-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $dark-primary,
    accent: $dark-accent,
    warn: $dark-warn
  ),
  typography: $typography-config
));
```

**And don't forget to apply hierarchy:**

```
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($typography-config);
```

**2. Concerning dark theme**

Please note that if you define a dark theme alonside with a light theme, you shoud not use:

```
.theme-light {
    @include mat.all-component-themes($theme-light);
}

.theme-dark {
    @include mat.all-component-themes($theme-dark);
}

@include mat.typography-hierarchy($typography-config);
```

but instead, use:

```
.theme-light {
    @include mat.all-component-themes($theme-light);
}

.theme-dark {
    @include mat.all-component-colors($theme-dark);
}

@include mat.typography-hierarchy($typography-config);
```

By doing it the right way, **you will avoid typography definition duplication**.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Do you know how to make this apply to regular tags too (h1, h2, p, etc.)

Comment: would you please add a plunker ?

Answer (score 8):

Do this When using custom theme for latest angular material (12) 
**styles.scss**

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;
@font-face {
   font-family: 'custom-font';
   src: url('assets/custom-font.ttf');
 }
$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $font-family: "custom-font"
);
@include mat.core($custom-typography);
```

Comment: That's the best for Angular v13 :) Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for V15 as mat.core() no longer takes any arguments- any ideas on what needs to change?

Answer (score 5):

**Few methods are deprecated in Angular Material 13. To change the default font family in Angular Material the new methods/configuration is below**

1. First change the css link of font in `index.html` file.

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Titillium+Web:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
>
```

2. Second write below configuration in `styles.scss` file

```
$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config($font-family:'"Titillium Web",sans-serif');

$custom-theme: mat.define-light-theme((typography: $custom-typography));

@include mat.core($custom-typography);
@include mat.all-component-themes($custom-theme);
```

Answer (score 5):

In Angular 15,

```
    $my-typography: mat.define-typography-config($font-family: '"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif');
    
    @include mat.typography-hierarchy($my-typography);

$my-app-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-app-primary,
    accent: $my-app-accent,
    warn: $my-app-warn,
  ),
  typography: $my-typography
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily override the `mat-typography-config` to set the font type and values of different variables

```
.custom-typography {
  @include angular-material-typography($custom-typography);
}

$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: "Quicksand, sans-serif",
);
```

Take look at the article https://www.universal-tutorial.com/angular-tutorials/angular-typography which has a demo as well.