# How to customize h1 typography in Angular Material app

Tags: angular, angular-material

## Summary

When setting up a simple angular material project with typography selected, and following [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#typography-config), I'm left asking: what is the appropriate way to customize typography in Angular 16?

## Details

I created a simple angular app that enabled typography and set up scss stylesheets.

I want to control the typography settings in the app and so in my `styles.scss` I added:

```scss
$my_typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $headline-1: mat.define-typography-level(40px, 20px, 900),
);
```

The large font here is for my testing, to see that it's working.

And then I include it on the theme declaration [as the documentation states](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography#typography-config):

```scss
$my-app-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my_app_primary,
    accent: $my_app_accent,
    warn: $my_app_warn,
  ),
  typography: $my_typography
));
```

And `ng` added this to my `body` tag:

```html
<body class="mat-typography">
```

So when I try to run this in my `app.component.html`:

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
```

The Roboto 700(bold) 32px Normal Black font is rendered.

How do I configure customization for the headings with angular material typography?

Comment: This problem is located in [this repository](https://github.com/mhedgpeth/hello-typography) for those who want that view of it.

Comment: Look for later answers that are more up-to-date, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75967975/215552).