# a tag css not working for text in 'a' tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply the gotham font to my buttons, but nothing seems to be catching, when I inspect the index running and go to the element, it shows font-family as gotham , but the text does not look like gotham. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Gotham';
    src: url("assets\fonts\Gotham-Bold.otf") format('embedded-opentype');
    src: url("assets\fonts\Gotham-Light.otf") format('embedded-opentype');
}

a:link, a:visited {
        font-family: Gotham;
        text-align: right;
        color: white;
        background: #005870;
        border: none;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-top: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 65%;
        transition: .4s;
        text-decoration: none;
}


a:hover, a:active {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        color: #005870;
        background: white;
        transition: .4s;
        text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="h1s" style="background:transparent;">
    <img src = "environmental-care.jpg" id="frame"/>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href="" id="introID">Intro</a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href=""><b>ON THE</b> <span class="light">SURFACE</span></a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href=""><b>FROM</b> <span class="light">ORE TO OIL</span></a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href=""><b>ENVIRONMENTAL</b> <span class="light">CARE</span></a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href=""><b>MUCH MORE THAN</b> <span class="light">GASOLINE</span></a>

    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <a class = "h1" href=""><b>ONE MORE</b> <span class="light">THING</span></a>
    <br><br>
    <div class="h1padding"></div>
    <div class="h1padding"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Open the network tab in the developer tools in your browser. Look to see if the font is loading successfully. It looks like you have the wrong kind of slashes in your URLs.

Comment: You sure the path is correct? Looks like you need to change `\ to /`

Comment: The path should be correct, also i changed the slashes to / from \, still when i load the page, in network the fonts dont seem to be downloading

Comment: Then double check the paths are correct. *should be* isn't *definitely is* ;)

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245141/using-otf-fonts-on-web-browsers

Comment: Double checked the paths, and the files are exactly where they should be , the thing thats tripping me up is that im not even getting a 404 for the font files, theyre just not even showing up on the network tab when i load the page

Comment: Could it be because the two fonts you're defining are bold and light but when you use the font in your style, you aren't setting the text to bold or light? Maybe it's expecting a 'regular' weight font but can't find it?

Comment: Or maybe split the fonts into separate fontfaces like so - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2436830/5392786

Comment: Tried splitting it into two, but still no luck :/

Comment: Gahhhhhh, it seems chrome doesnt care about the  format('embedded-opentype');, i removed that and it works !!!! :)

Comment: Nice! Make sure you consider other font types for maximum support (should you require it) - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:
Chrome doesnt care about the  format, removed that and it is working :)

```
src: url("assets\fonts\Gotham-Bold.otf") format('embedded-opentype');
src: url("assets\fonts\Gotham-Light.otf") format('embedded-opentype');
```

changed to:

```
src: url("assets\fonts\Gotham-Bold.otf");    
src: url("assets\fonts\Gotham-Light.otf");
```