# Downloaded font won't display properly

Tags: css, fonts

I downloaded a font and in my CSS I have :

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Gotham Medium";
src: url("Gotham/Gotham-Medium.otf");}
```

When I call say in

```
 h1 { font-family:'Gotham Medium'}
```

the font display does not match what Gotham should look like. Nor is it a default font.

Is the problem a matter of something being changed when downloaded in my laptop ? 
The font is not in the google API so I can't try with an external link.

Comment: Open developer console and check network tab, make sure you are getting 200 instead of 404

Comment: The page where the css is, gets status ' Finished'.

Comment: inspect your h1 tag, in web debugger and you will see what font is used

Comment: That's the thing. It says it uses Gotham Medium font, but it's not the same font as it is on the page. I thought maybe when downloading some encodings get lost or something.
Cuz the name of the font is the one I import, but it's not how it's displayed.

Comment: use [**font-squirrel**](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to generate web-fonts

Comment: Thank you. Says the font I'm uploading is blacklisted though

Comment: try using a different font format perhaps otf isnt supported by your particular browser, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245141/using-otf-fonts-on-web-browsers

Comment: Do you own a legitimate license for Gotham? It’s rights are maneaged by Hoefler & Co. It’s not free.

Answer (score 2):

Your Css should be like this :

```
@font-face {
     font-family: 'MyWebFont';
     src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
     src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
     url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

[css Trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

To do this you can use a generator for font-face but you must have the license for the web font