# @font-face help it do not work

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I created this test file

```
<h1> test <h1>
```

Then in CSS3, I did this

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'hello';
src:url('/fonts/HelloStockholm-Alt.otf')
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 100;
} 

h1 {
font-family: hello;
font-weight: 100;
}
```

And this is the font I downloaded

https://www.dafont.com/de/hello-stockholm.font

Hopefully some of you guys can help me

Comment: Maybe this link can help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340584/downloaded-font-wont-display-properly/47345855#47345855](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340584/downloaded-font-wont-display-properly/47345855#47345855)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to write `;` at the end of the code

src:url('/fonts/HelloStockholm-Alt.otf');

**UPDATE**

Ok. I found right answer. I made your little project in my local and I downloaded font. It's not `.otf` file, it's `.ttf` file.
You just change type `.otf` to `.ttf`

Also if your html out of fonts folder then remove the `/` from font source. And maybe you renamed font file when I downloaded name was like that `HelloStockholm-Regular`

```
src:url('fonts/HelloStockholm-Regular.ttf');
```

Finally You forgot closed here `h1` ;)

```
<h1> test </h1>
```

Hope it'll helps you. Good luck!)

Comment: Oh sorry yes i see but that was not the problem

Comment: Ok. I found where's the problem ;)

Comment: If answer helps give up vote and check please like "this answer is useful" Thanks ;) @Enes

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove '/' before fonts

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'hello';
src:url('fonts/HelloStockholm-Alt.otf');
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 100;
} 

h1 {
font-family: 'hello';
font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: I already DELETED the fonts folder so there is only the nameofthefont.otf