# Problems when loading local fonts in css with font-face

Tags: html, css, django

I'm working with html and CSS, and I need to load a font which is in my local storage, but it gives me the following error:

downloadable font: download failed

I'm using font-face to try to load it, but it doesn't work. I'm working with mozilla-firefox for linux mint. Hope anyone can help me

This is what i've tried:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'qebab';
 src: local('qebab'), url('fonts/qebab-webfont.ttf')format('truetype');
}
```

and then I try to use it in my class

```
.important-font {
    font-family: 'qebab';
}
```

Comment: Probably you have to set the correct path for the font. Try to check your console browser (press f12 on mozilla) and check if the path is correct

Comment: Or check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340584/downloaded-font-wont-display-properly/47345855#47345855)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using custom fonts using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144000/using-custom-fonts-using-css)?

Comment: Are you sure the font name is "qebab"? The only font I can find online is "Qebab Shadow".

Comment: @MrLister yes, I'm pretty sure, because I modified the name to make it easier