# How to implement default fonts to my web page

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

How can I inplement a deffault fonts to my web page.
I have file with fonts, all I need to know is how to implement it?

Best wishes and thanks !!!

Comment: I am still doing my reasearch

Comment: Search about font-face and you will find a lot of tutorials how about use it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340584/downloaded-font-wont-display-properly/47345855#47345855](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340584/downloaded-font-wont-display-properly/47345855#47345855) for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloaded font won't display properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340584/downloaded-font-wont-display-properly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

correct you can use this css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;      
  src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

also, for complete code usage please refer to [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)

all the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS code to define a new font face (using truetype fonts as an example).

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'Your Font Name Here';
  src:url('path-to-your-font.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Then, you can use your font as you normally would in CSS.

Comment: I alredy have file with fonts on my machine. One file is fonts.TrueType font file and the other is fonts condensed.TrueType font file