# @font-face wont display

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have a custom local font that i am trying to load, but it just wont display. I have checked about all the stack exchange posts about this subject and none of the provided solutions seem to work.

I have tried absolute paths, relative paths, clearing the cache and other things like using different names what ever.
But it wont display :(

See here my current setup:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boilerplate/fonts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">

<div id="grid_item_2" class="text_center">
    <h1>Bienvenido<br>a Some app</h1>
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium nostrum accusamus, unde excepturi placeat sapiente explicabo rerum iusto? Mollitia commodi vitae veniam quasi.</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

font css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Lilita;
    src: url(../../Data/Frontend/Fonts/LilitaOne.ttf) format('ttf');
}
```

Index css:

```
#grid_item_2 h1 {
    font-family: Lilita;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #000;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #4C4C4C;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: rgb(255, 180, 17);
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

Here is the file structure to all the relevant files:
Path to the css:
[image]

Path to the fonts:
[image]

If there is any information missing or needed please let me know!
I am very desperate atm

Comment: Try to look at this topic [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340584/downloaded-font-wont-display-properly/47345855#47345855](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340584/downloaded-font-wont-display-properly/47345855#47345855)

Comment: @Sfili_81 yeah this font generator fixed it.. I have no clue why.. But it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose font path inside quote (' ' or " ") and change the format text to `truetype` instead of `ttf`.
It is best to use lower-case for font URL.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Lilita';
src: url('../../data/frontend/fonts/lilitaone.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```